# Sort a value list that contains letters and also numbers in a specific order

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem in SQL Oracle, I'm trying to create a view that contains values with letters and numbers and I want to sort them in a specific order.

Here is my query:

```
create or replace view table1_val (val, msg_text) as 
select 
    val, msg_text
from 
    table_val
where 
    val in ('L1','L2','L3','L4','L5','L6','L7','L8','L9','L10','L11','L12','L13','L14','G1','G2','G3','G4') 
order by lpad(val, 3);
```

The values are displayed like this:

```
G1,G2,G3,G4,L1,L2,L3,L4,L5,L6,L7,L8,L9,L10,L11,L12,L13
```

The thing is that I want to display the `L` values first and then the `G` values like in the where condition. The 'val' column is `VARCHAR2(3 CHAR)`. The `msg_text` column is irrelevant. Can someone help me with that? I use Oracle 12C.

Comment: If G vs. L encode different information from the numeric part, then why are both stored in a single column? You should have them in separate columns, then you wouldn't have to ask such questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must interpret the second part of the `val` column as a number

```
order by 
  case when val like 'L%' then 0 else 1 end,
  to_number(substr(val,2))
```

This work fine for your current data, but may fail in future if a new record is added with non-numeric structure.

More conservative (and more hard to write), but safe would be to used a decode for all the current keys, ordering unknown keys on the last position (`id = 18` in the example):

```
order by 
decode(
'L1',1,
'L2',2,
'L3',3,
'L4',4,
'L5',5,
'L6',6,
'L7',7,
'L8',8,
'L9',9,
'L10',10,
'L11',11,
'L12',12,
'L13',13,
'G1',14,
'G2',15,
'G3',16,
'G4',17,18)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do anything based on the order of the `WHERE` condition

But you can use a `CASE`  on the `ORDER BY`

```
ORDER BY CASE 
            WHEN SUBSTR(val, 1, 1) = 'L' THEN 1
            WHEN SUBSTR(val, 1, 1) = 'G' THEN 2
            ELSE 3
         END,
         TO_NUMBER (SUBSTR(val, 2, 10));
```

Comment: I can't change the values. It should be L1 and not L01.

Comment: Check again,, use `TO_NUMBER`  to solve the missing 0 in strings

Answer (score 0):

Another option to consider might be using regular expressions, such as

```
SQL> with table1_val (val) as
  2    (select 'L1'   from dual union all
  3     select 'L26'  from dual union all
  4     select 'L3'   from dual union all
  5     select 'L21'  from dual union all
  6     select 'L11'  from dual union all
  7     select 'L4'   from dual union all
  8     select 'G88'  from dual union all
  9     select 'G10'  from dual union all
 10     select 'G2'   from dual
 11    )
 12  select val
 13  from table1_val
 14  order by regexp_substr(val, '^[[:alpha:]]+') desc,
 15           to_number(regexp_substr(val, '\d+$'));

VAL
---
L1
L3
L4
L11
L21
L26
G2
G10
G88

9 rows selected.

SQL>
```